# How to create box shadow variables?

Tags: dynamic, box-shadow

I am new to CSS and HTML. Having come from WPF background, I am trying to achieve shadow effect which I can pre-define (just like defining Effects in WPF and calling them wherever required using DynamicResource).

I want to define a shadow like this:

```css
 --boxShadow1: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
```

and use it in CSS whenever I need it like this:

```css
box-shadow: var(--boxShadow1);
```

How do I do this?
If a pure CSS solution is not possible, is there any other way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://sass-lang.com/

sass also likes css

sass box shadow code

@mixin box-shadow($x-axis: 0, $y-axis: 1px, $blur: 2px, $color: $default)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But is it possible to do this only in CSS?